# How to replace a column value in a variable with a variable using awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have two variables:

```
var=x
out=1,2,3,4,5
```

I want to replace the third column in $out with $var. I am able to substitute x for 3 in column 3 with the following command (I speak of columns in $out as these will be the values for a database insert statement):

```
echo $out | awk -F ',' -v new=, '{$3="x" ; print}'
```

The output then is:

```
1 2 x 4 5
```

However using $var instead of x with the following command does not work:

```
echo $out | awk -F ',' -v new=, '{$3=$var; print}'
```

The output then is:

```
1 2 1,2,3,4,5 4 5
```

The final problem is that the output is not comma separated.
So what I am trying to achieve is the following output:

```
1,2,x,4,5
```

where x is the current value of $var. Does anyone have a clue how this could be done.

Comment: Where `$var` was used in `awk` - `var` was an unset awk variable, `$var` indicated a field reference to `$0` (which is the current record/line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to supply the shell variable to `awk` as an awk variable, for example, using `-v`:

```
awk -F , -v OFS=, -v new="$var" '{$3=new; print}' <<<"$out"
```

The shell variable `$var` is supplied to `awk` as `new`. Within the awk program, `new` is used to reference this variable. awk's output field separator (`OFS`) can also be set like this.

- Note that with this method, `awk` will interpret backslashes in `$var` as escape sequences. To avoid that, you can place shell variables in awk's environment, accessed within the awk program via the `ENVIRON` array:

```
new="$var" awk -F , -v OFS=, '{$3=ENVIRON["new"]; print}' <<<"$out"
```

In the shell, it's usually best to quote parameter expansions (like `"$var"`), otherwise the expansion is subject to filename generation (aka *globbing*) & `IFS` field splitting.

Comment: To be clear: *awk program* refers to the argument `{$3=new; print}`. See `man awk`.

Comment: Thanks user1187233. Your recommendation has solved both problems. Much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is when using `'` you can not expand shell variables , you must use `"`.

But if you start using `"`  you must prevent some substitutions by a `\`

A solution will be :

```
echo $out | awk -F ',' -v new=, "{\$3=\"$var\" ; print}"
```